# 'find' optimization

Tags: c++, c, linux

```
'find ./ -name *.jpg'
```

I am trying to optimize 'find' command for the above statement.

method which handle the '-name' predicate in find implementation.

---

```
static boolean

pred__name __common (const char *pathname, const char *str, int flags)

{

   boolean b;

   char *base = base_name (pathname);

   strip__trailing __slashes(base);

   b = fnmatch (str, base, flags) == 0;

   free (base);

   return b;

}
```

---

since I am looking for file extensions and want to avoid the regular expression based string matching, I replaced 'b = fnmatch (str, base, flags) == 0;' with following statements

```
int strLen = strlen(base);

b = FNM_NOMATCH;

if  (strLen>=4 && (str[3] == base[strLen]) && 
    (str[2] == base[strLen -1]) && (str[1] ==   
    base[strLen-2]) && (str[0] == base[strLen-3]))

{

b = 0;

}
```

After this I expected some performance gain, but I don't see any kind of performance gain after the above change.

1. Is that I am doing some thing wrong?
2. is there a better way to optimize the 'find' to search only for file extensions?

Comment: after profiling I have some better numbers on fnmatch - CPU usage, fnmatch it is taking nearly 16% of CPU for this activity.

I think, I can not reduce the total time required to run find(as Thomas told it is more of disk activity) but it should be possible to reduce the CPU usage of find with some more optimization.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that the regex matching is the bottleneck. Since `find` traverses the filesystem, the overhead is probably in disk seek times, and in case of an in-memory filesystem, in system calls and the resulting context switches.

Comment: if the overhead is only in disk seek times then CPU usage should not be 30%.
only 2 major parts in find
1. filesystem iteration(low CPU operation)

2. parsing files(high CPU operation)

Comment: @kolari: you should do some profiling and find out where the time is actually spent. Just optimizing a random part of the program won't help much.

Comment: +1 that the bottleneck is not in the pattern matching.  Also, the -name switch does not even do full regex, it just does the much simpler typical shell glob expansion.